# Decreasing the range of a dataset

Tags: r, dataset, range

I have a dataset which ranges from 0.00000787 to 1.39151821, quite a large disparity when it comes to plotting the data. I'd like to try and decrease the range of data so the plot (I'm using a colour coded plot, and right now it's pretty monotonous) is more visually understandable. I tried using log(dataset) however this creates some negative numbers which my software doesn't like.

Mathematics is not my strong point, if someone could recommend a method of fitting my data into a smaller range it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try log + 1, like this:

```
 list<-seq(0.00000787,1.39151821,0.01)
 plot(log(list+1))
```

[image: plot]